# In Django, cannot delete model instance because of FK in second (and view-based) model

Tags: django, delete-row, sql-view

I defined in Django two models, the second one is based on the first, and is not managed because it is based backend on a SQL Server view (not on a table)

```
class Embedder(models.Model):
  {my_fields...}

class MostRecent(models.Model):
  embedder = models.ForeignKey(Embedder)
  status = models.IntegerField()

  class Meta:
    db_table = 'embedder_most_recent'
    managed = False
```

The problem is that I can't delete an instance of Embedder because of this error:

```
View or function 'embedder_most_recent' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables. (4405) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

The problem seems to reside in Django since I can delete the embedder row in SQL without error. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [marcusshep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3569921/marcusshep) already posted, there is sufficient documentation for this behavior in the Django docs.

Since a Django `ForeignKey` references another Django model object, any attempt to delete the parent object means Django must find a way to manage objects referencing the  `ForeignKey`. You should specify this behavior explicitly.

The example below will delete the object containing the `ForeignKey`:

```
class MostRecent(models.Model):
   embedder = models.ForeignKey(Embedder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   status = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining an alternate on delete. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: URL outdated and needs updating.